# Pulling Findings from AWS GuardDuty

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-guardduty

I am trying to pull data from AWS GuardDuty from an AWS account. I am running into to issues where the account will connect but not gather any findings and post to my threatdetection.html page. I have the access_key, secret_key, and DETECTOR_ID all previously defined earlier in the file.

```
@app.route('/threatdetection')
@login_required
def guardduty_alerts():
   client = boto3.client('guardduty', aws_access_key_id=session['access_key'], 
   aws_secret_access_key=session['secret_key'], region_name='us-east-1'

    try:
       list_findings_response = client.list_findings(DetectorId=DETECTOR_ID)
       finding_ids = list_findings_response['FindingIds']

       if finding_ids:
          findings_response = client.get_findings(DetectorId=DETECTOR_ID, 
          FindingIds=finding_ids)
          findings = findings_response['Findings']
       else:
          findings = []

       return render_template('threatdetection.html', findings=findings)

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
       print("Error getting findings:", e)
       return render_template('threatdetection.html', findings=[])
```

Comment: Is guardduty in the default region? If not, you need to specify the region

Comment: @titiwon GuardDuty is enabled in us-east-1. What do you mean by "default region". I also specified the region_name in the function.

Comment: Sorry I did not see that you added the region to the client. It seems that the issue is different. Deafult region could come from aws config or env variables.

Comment: I don't know what render_template does, but if that triggered a botcore error, you would also post no findings. I would try to add more logs or prints.

Comment: @titiwon render_template calls the html file and posts the data there in a table. There are no errors that are being posted in the console. I really have no idea why it isn't pulling any data or posting any error logs.